# Adding a column vector inside figure's caption, problem

Tags: amsmath

I want to add a column vector inside a figure's caption, but it just doesn't work. However, I could write math inside captions, normally.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw [step=0.5, thin, gray!40] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{I want to add a column vector in here}
%\caption{the vector $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}k \\ m\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have commented the line which gives me the error.

Comment: Maybe you want `$\binom{k}{m}$` command?

Comment: No, I have tried that, it gives the same error.

Comment: I have no error here with binom.

Comment: This is so strange. I get this `Argument of \@caption has an extra }.` after I used what you have suggested `\caption{the vector $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\binom{k}{m}\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}`

Comment: No. Replace all math by only `$\binom{k}{m}$`. You don't need the matrix.

Comment: Such errors may happen from a missing `{` some where else, for instance one mistypes `{ ... )` instead of `{ ... }`.

Comment: Sigur, my bad, but your way will not work if I want to use square brackets [] instead of ( ), right?

Comment: @TahaMagdy You can use abuse the definition of `\genfrac` (on which `\binom` is based) as `\caption{the vector $\protect\genfrac[]{0pt}{}{k}{m}$}`. The `\protect` is essential. This of course won't work with three-dimensional vectors. But as pointed out in the second answer to the duplicate question, I believe using the optional parameter is the best solution. Seeing a vector in the list of figures isn't particularly useful. And if you are not going to print a list of figures at all, using `\caption[]{...}` (i.e. with an empty optional argument) is even simpler.